# SF3 [Translator][Console] translation:update yaml nesting

Tags: php, symfony, nested, yaml, translate

I am using Symfony 3.4 and I have a question.

Nesting translations message codes (the dot being the separator) is a great feature of YAML translation files:

```
admin:
    title: Administration
    exit: Exit administration
```

Translation:update generate:

```
admin.title: Administration
admin.exit: Exit administration
```

I run the following command to update the yaml file:

```
php bin/console translation:update --output-format=yml  --force fr  NameBundle
```

In my code, I use this syntax to translate the keys:

```
{{ 'layout.confirm.delete'|trans }}
```

Do you have an idea for generate nested yml files with the translation:update command?

Answer (score 2):

The multiple levels are flattened into single id/translation pairs by adding a dot (.) between every level, 
therefore this definition:

```
admin:
    title: Administration
    exit: Exit administration
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
admin.title: Administration
admin.exit: Exit administration
```

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/components/translation/usage.html#creating-translations)

Comment: The problem is that my command generates a YML file that contains 'inline' keys.
As you say, I want the file to generate nested keys, which is not the case.